# find all irreducible polynomials of degree 2 and 3 over Z5

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I would like to find all irreducible polynomials of degree 2 and 3 with coefficients in Z5.

I know that the polynomial (x^5)^n - x equals with the product of all monic irreducible polynomials of degree d , where d divides n. But i don't know how to proceed from that point. Any ideas?

Comment: Such a polynomials reduces iff it has a root. From there a computer search is straightforward, just looping over each polynomial and plugging in each element of $\mathbb{Z} / 5$. I’ll try and think if this can be reduced to a hand computation.

Comment: Use reduction. Any quadratic can be reduced to $a[(x−b)^2+c]$ so we can generate all irreducibles by just considering $x^2+c$. Similarly we need only to test $x^3+cx+d$ for the cubic case.

Comment: Are you sure you need to find them all? There are 10 and 40 of them (of the respective degrees 2 and 3). You can cut down the lengths of those lists by a factor of five with the trick from Oscar Lanzi's comment.

Comment: Well, i think i got it right! Using the theorem I mentioned above and getting help from this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1607662/771919, i found all monic irreducible polynomials of degree 2. Then, having found all monic irreducible polynomials of degree 1 or 2 i can make out of them the 85 monic polynomials of degree 3 that are reducible. And so the rest of them are the ones i want.

Thank you all for your help!